# Extracting value after calculating the minimum distance between points from a spatial transect

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, latitude-longitude

Suppose I have a matrix in the following format derived through

https://www.mediafire.com/file/n1bds3eo7n8p34c/Bank_Farm_2_elev.tif

```
    setwd("D:/Gs Data")
    require(raster)
    require(rgdal)

    GDALinfo("Bank_Farm_2_elev.tif")
    DEM <- raster("Bank_Farm_2_elev.tif")
    test_xyz <- rasterToPoints(DEM)
    colnames(test_xyz) <- c("xt", "yt", "Elev")

    plot(DEM,
    maxpixels=ncell(DEM),
    col = grey(1:100/100),
    main= "LIDAR data")
```

The aim is to extract a transect from the lower left corner to the upper right corner. Calculating the minimum distance between points and deriving the value for that location from the third column. Thus, creating a 1D transect of data from the 3rd column. Simple illustration:

[draw_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLEz6.png)

I have found the following code in matlab for doing this:

%Putting the measured value at each point on the transect in a variable called zt

```
    for (j in 1:528) { % assuming nr of points for the transect. Transect 
    coordinates in xt and yt
      myMinDist=9999999 % initialise the variable to a very large number
      for (i in 1:length(text_xyz)) { % assuming the amount of points in the 
    whole dataset to search trhough and find the point that lies on the 
    transect
        if ((sqrt((xt(j)-x(i))^2+(yt(j)-y(i))^2))<myMinDist){ % test to try 
    and get the point closes to our transect point xt(i) and yt(i)
          myMinDist=sqrt((xt(j)-x(i))^2+(yt(j)-y(i))^2) % update minDist
          zt(j)=(zi)
          }
      }
    }
```

Which I have tried to re-write to R for the attached .tif data file

```
    for (j in 1:528) { # the number of rows when dataset is plotted as .tif 
    file (given by 'dimensions' in the GDALInfo() command)
      for (i in 1:length(test_xyz)) { # although length of test_xyz does not 
      line up with ncell?
        if ((sqrt((test_xyz["xt"][j]-x[i])^2+(test_xyz["yt"][j]-y[i])^2))
    <myMinDist) {
          myMinDist=sqrt((test_xyz["xt"][j]-x[i])^2+(test_xyz["yt"][j]-y[i])^2)
        } else { 
          test_xyz["Elev"][j]=(zi)
        }
      }
    }
```

I think the key point that I am missing is setting up an empty vector to write my output in and a proper distinction between assigning xt and x, yt and y, zt and z within the code.
Looking forward to suggestions.

Regards.

Comment: No one? Please let me know if the reproducible example is unclear

Comment: I.e. how can I get the corner coordinates for the rotated shape of the .tiff file in order to draw a line parallel to the length of the field (say: from the lowest corner to the corner furthest on the x-axis) and then calculate the intercept and slope for a simple yt = a xt + b equation?